# Creating a graphing of a mathematical function in Javascript that dynamically changes as variables change in the function

Tags: javascript, plot

I am trying to create a javascript app that allow users to see a graph of a function with multiple variables.For my program, I want the use the variable S as the dependent variable for the graph and use all other variables as constant parameters. However, I want the user to be able to change value of the parameters and I want the graph to be updated according to those changes. I tried to do that with my program, but it seems that the graph would not even show up. How would I address this issue? Also, should I use another plotting script? Down below is my code. For all those interested in finance, you may notice that I am trying to plot the value of a call option with the Black-Scholes formula.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/tests/../src/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/tests/../src/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://distributome.googlecode.com/svn-history/r375/trunk/js/calc/distributions.js"></script>





<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jqplot.com/tests/../src/jquery.jqplot.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/tests/../src/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/tests/../src/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>












<script class="code" type="text/javascript">

function invoke () {
Sigma = quad.variance.value; 
K = quad.strike_price.value;
r = quad.r_val.value;
div = quad.div_val.value;
graph ();
}





function answer(S) {
    d1 = (Math.log( S / K )+(r - div + .5*Math.pow(Sigma, 2))*T)/(Sigma*Math.sqrt(T));
    d2 = d1 - Sigma*Math.sqrt(T); 
    return S*Math.exp(-div*T)*stdNormalCDF(d1) - K*Math.exp(-r*T)*stdNormalCDF(d2);
};






function graph() {

  var CallPoints = []; 
  for (var i=0; i<90; i+=0.1){ 
     CallPoints.push([i, answer(i)]); 
  } 
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [CallPoints], {  
      series:[{showMarker:false}],
      axes:{
        xaxis:{
          label:'Stock Price'
        },
        yaxis:{
          label:'Premium'
        }
      }
  });
};

</script>



</head>
    <body onload="invoke()">


<form name="quad" onchange="invoke()">

<input type="text" value=".30" name="variance" size="5" onchange="invoke()"> = Volatility
<br>
<input type="text" value="30" name="strike_price" size="5" onchange="invoke()"> = K
<br>
<input type="text" value=".05" name="r_val" size="5" onchange="invoke()" > = r
<br>
<input type="text" value=".05" name="div_val" size="5" onchange="invoke()"> = div
<br>
<input type="text" value="1" name="T_val" size="5" onchange="invoke()"> = T

</form>
    <div id="chart1" style="height: 300px; width: 500px; position: relative;" class="jqplot-target">
    </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

T is not defined in invoke() function
add line:

T = quad.T_val.value;